# checking individual element of an array by calling a method

Tags: javascript

Can i optimize my code bit more to reduce number of line?

I am checking/passing individual array elements? Can i make it re-write in a generic way?

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.studentReport.Students.length; i++)
{
    if (_isValueNan($$scope.studentReport.Students[i].Age))
        $$scope.studentReport.Students[i].Age = null;

    if (_isValueNan($$scope.studentReport.Students[i].Number))
        $$scope.studentReport.Students[i].Number = null;

    if (_isValueNan($$scope.studentReport.Students[i].Height))
        $$scope.studentReport.Students[i].Height = null;
}


var _isValueNan = function (item) {
    var result = false;
    if (typeof item == 'number' && isNaN(item))
        result = true;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nullify the property internally in the function, and also pass the item and property value in independently. For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.studentReport.Students.length; i++)
{
    _checkValueNan($$scope.studentReport.Students[i], "Age");
    _checkValueNan($$scope.studentReport.Students[i], "Number");
    _checkValueNan($$scope.studentReport.Students[i], "Height");
}


var _checkValueNan = function (item, valueName) {
    if (typeof item[valueName] == 'number' && isNaN(item[valueName]))
        item[valueName] = null;
}
```

EDIT:
Leading on from Vicky Gonsalves answer, you could additionally check ANY of the properties of the object, which might be a more scalable solution.

```
var _checkAllValueNan = function (item) {
    for(var key in item) { // iterates all item properties
        if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue; // ensures not prop of prototype
        if (typeof item[key] == 'number' && isNaN(item[key])) item[key] = null;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.studentReport.Students.length; i++)
{
    _checkAllValueNan($scope.studentReport.Students[i]);
}
```

Comment: It works nice. i just did small change to loop i.e,  $scope.studentReport.Students.ForEach(item){.............} it looks nicer than tradional for loop.

Answer (score 3):

With ref to Stumblor's answer:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.studentReport.Students.length; i++) {
    _checkValueNan($$scope.studentReport.Students[i], ["Age", "Number", "Height"]);
}

var _checkValueNan = function (item, values) {
    values.forEach(function (val) {
        if (typeof item[val] === 'number' && isNaN(item[val])) item[val] = null;
    });
}
```

Comment: @ Stumblor, did not get your above line.. can give an example refering to my question? please

Comment: @immirza sure - i've done an edit to my answer to show what I mean.